# Angular Conditional Routing based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Is it possible to place a condition on component property of a route?

For example,

```
let routes: Routes = [];

routes = [
    {path: '',  
      if (data == 1)
        { component: component1 } }
]
```

Or is there a way to do conditional routing without the use of auth guards?

Comment: nope, use guards for this or separate paths.

Comment: Implement route guard, https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-canactivate-introduction-routing-guards#:~:text=Angular%20route%20guards%20are%20interfaces,%2C%20CanLoad%2C%20CanDeactivate%20and%20Resolve.

Comment: Anyway, what is wrong with implementing guard for that ?

Answer (score -2):

{
path:'',
component: (() => {
return (data==1) ? component1;
})()
}